# Image Slider - How to change the order of the images

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, slider

I am using a Fullscreen background image slider in my Wordpress theme.

Now the problem is that I do not have any control over the order on which the images are loaded. When I remove the images and upload them again(via wordpress), the order is different. When I upload them all at once, it orders them alphabetically. When I upload them one by one, the order is random.

As you can see in the slider settings below - Random is disabled

Here is the script that controls the slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    jQuery.supersized({

        // Functionality
        slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
        autoplay                :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
        start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
        image_path              :   '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/supersized/',
        stop_loop               :   <?php echo $slideshow_pause_on_last; ?>,            // Pauses slideshow on last slide
        random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
        slide_interval          :   <?php echo $slideshow_interval; ?>,     // Length between transitions
        transition              :   <?php echo $slideshow_transition; ?>,           // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
        transition_speed        :   <?php echo $slideshow_transition_speed; ?>,     // Speed of transition
        new_window              :   0,          // Image links open in new window/tab
        pause_hover             :   <?php echo $slideshow_pause_hover; ?>,          // Pause slideshow on hover
        keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
        performance             :   2,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
        image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

        // Size & Position                         
        min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
        min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
        vertical_center         :   <?php echo $slideshow_vertical_center; ?>,          // Vertically center background
        horizontal_center       :   <?php echo $slideshow_horizontal_center; ?>,            // Horizontally center background
        fit_always              :   <?php echo $slideshow_fit_always; ?>,           // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
        fit_portrait            :   <?php echo $slideshow_portrait; ?>,         // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
        fit_landscape           :   <?php echo $slideshow_landscape; ?>,            // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

        // Components                           
        slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'number', 'name', 'blank')
        thumb_links             :   1,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
        thumbnail_navigation    :   0,          // Thumbnail navigation
        slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images


<?php 
// Don't Populate list if no Featured page is set
$bg_slideshow = of_get_option ('general_bgslideshow');

if ($bg_choice=="Image Attachments Slideshow") { $bg_slideshow = $post->ID; }
if ($bg_choice=="Fullscreen Post Slideshow" ) { $bg_slideshow = $fullscreen_slideshowpost; }

if ( $bg_slideshow <>"" ) {

    // Grab all image attachements from the featured page
    $images =& get_children( array( 
                                'post_parent' => $bg_slideshow,
                                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                                'order' => 'ASC',
                                'numberposts' => $thelimit,
                                'orderby' => 'menu_order' )
                                );

    // Loop through the images
    foreach ( $images as $id => $image ) {
        $attatchmentID = $image->ID;
        $imagearray = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attatchmentID , 'full', false);
        $imageURI = $imagearray[0];
        $imageID = get_post($attatchmentID);
        $imageTitle = apply_filters('the_title',$image->post_title);
        $imageDesc = apply_filters('the_title',$image->post_content);
        $postlink = get_permalink($image->post_parent);
        // If linking is On
        if ($featured_linked == 1 || $featured_linked == true) {
            $attatchmentURL = get_attachment_link($image->ID);
        }
        // Count
        $count++;
        if ($count>1) { echo ","; }

        $slideshow_title="";
        $slideshow_caption="";

        if ($imageTitle) $slideshow_title='<div class="slideshow_title">'.$imageTitle.'</div>';
        if ($imageDesc) $slideshow_caption='<div class="slideshow_caption">'.$imageDesc.'</div>';

        echo "{image : '".$imageURI."', title : '". $slideshow_title . $slideshow_caption . "', url : ''}";
    }

// If Ends here for the Featured Page
}
?>
        ],
        progress_bar            :   1,          // Timer for each slide                         
        mouse_scrub             :   1
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to have some control over the order  - Anything but Random. How do I do that/What do I change in the script?

The theme that uses the slider - http://www.imaginemthemes.com/themes/?theme=RSW

Thank you!

Comment: is there any pattern in your .img file names?

Comment: nope...there names(titles) are unrelated

Comment: try 'orderby' => 'post_date' and drag and drop the images in the popup at back end

Comment: Thank you Moeed. What do you mean by the pop up? Also, I did try using post_date (without reordering anything) but the order did not change? must I reorder it again?

Comment: post_date means it will arrange your images according to the date they have been posted.
the area from where you are uploading the images, just drag and drop the images and check either the order of your images changed or not ?

Comment: thank you Moeed. Could you perhaps put this in an answer so I can close this?